# AWS Load Balancer Forward action stickiness

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So, I am using a module based on this [AWS LB Module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-alb)

Now, I'm trying to add stickiness option on the default_action forward. Not sure why it's not working. I've tried all sorts of changes. My last change is this:

```
  dynamic "default_action" {
    for_each = contains(["authenticate-oidc", "authenticate-cognito"], lookup(var.https_listeners[count.index], "action_type", {})) ? [var.https_listeners[count.index]] : []
    content {
      type             = "forward"
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main[lookup(default_action.value, "target_group_index", count.index)].id
      stickiness {
        enabled  = lookup(default_action.value, "stickiness", false)
        duration = lookup(default_action.value, "duration", null)
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to pass this:

```
  https_listeners = [
    {
      port            = 443
      protocol        = "HTTPS"
      certificate_arn = var.certificate_arn
      stickiness      = true
      duration        = 3600
    },
  ]
```

I'm now thinking of trying to just use the default stickiness as enabled, and duration 3600.

Any thoughts on this?

EDIT 1: I've tried changing the module block as @bryan mentioned I am passing an empty map. Just for test purposes, I hardcoded the values for stickiness like below:

```
  dynamic "default_action" {
    for_each = contains(["authenticate-oidc", "authenticate-cognito"], lookup(var.https_listeners[count.index], "action_type", {})) ? [var.https_listeners[count.index]] : []
    content {
      type             = "forward"
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main[lookup(default_action.value, "target_group_index", count.index)].id
      stickiness {
        enabled  = true
        duration = 3600
      }
    }
  }
```

Expectation is for the listener default action to set the group stickiness.. but somehow, it doesn't. I've also raised this issue on the AWS LB Module repo

Comment: Your foreach is a check against contains, but in the example here, that contains will evaluate to false, and the conditional will then fallback to `[]` as I understand it. So if you add a `authenticate-oidc` or `authenticate-cognito` to the map in the array of `https_listeners` you should be okay, I think. Let me know if that helps, and I'll make it a proper answer.

Comment: "Not sure why it's not working" - what does it mean? Any errors? Your description is not specific. What exactly is happening?

Comment: What's not working is that I don't see the stickiness happening when I look at the listener action in the AWS console.

@BryanHeden: I've tried actually modifying the module to hardcode to true, and 3600, and still didn't reflect on listener action

Comment: Like I said, that must be because of the first line in the `for_each` - you're essentially passing a `[]` to that module. Perhaps you're looking at the output of some other module. Set the `authenticate-oidc` map element for instance, and I suspect you see a completely different plan.

Comment: Yep, I tried to elimate that. So, I hardcoded the values instead just to test. (see my post edit.) Still didn't work.

Also, this is just part of the module from the official AWS LB Module. And I've raised it with them as well.